# Python: Multipledispatch(@dispatch) para función con parámetros predeterminados

Tags: python-3.x

¿Cómo queda el decorador @dispatch() de la librería multipledispatch para una función con parámetros predeterminados?

Comment: Nunca me acuerdo de cómo hacerlo y termino buscándolo y no encuentro. Al final lo saco por prueba y error, así que lo subo por si alguien más está como yo jeje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los parámetros predeterminados se ignoran, solo se marcan los no predeterminados.

INPUT:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

def foo(a, b, c="2022"):
  print(f"{a}-{b}-{c}")

@dispatch(str, str)
def faa(a, b, c="2022"):
  print(f"{a}-{b}-{c}")
  
@dispatch(str)
def faa(a, b="33", c="2022"):
  print(f"{a}-{b}-{c}")

  
        
foo("22","22")
faa("22")
faa("22","22")
faa("22",c="2025", b="23")
faa("22","22","2023")
```

OUTPUT:

22-22-2022

22-33-2022

22-22-2022

22-23-2025

22-22-2023